# I have executed a node js server on cPanel, it is succefully executing but still my server is not accessible using public IP address of my server

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, cpanel, web-hosting, cloud-hosting

I have executed a nodejs server on port 8080 on cPanel using SSH access.
I have provided public IP address of my server as a host name for node js server.
But still I m not able to access the server by entering the public IP address and port number in browser URL.

[image]

**Code:**

```
 'use strict';
  const Hapi = require('hapi');
  const server = Hapi.server({
  port: 8080,
  host: '1.1.1.1' //servers public IP adrress
  });
  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: (request, h) => {
      return 'Hello, world!';
      }
    });

  const init = async () => {
    await server.start();
    console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
  };
  process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
  });

init();
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: post some of your server side code.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem.

The problem was the port on which I was trying to run this application was not open to outside accessors.

I contacted to support team of cloud server on which I have deployed my application, and then they have opened the port.

And after opening the port now it is accessible to outside accessors.

Thank you for your time and efforts.